# Config wcf service for https/SSL on localhost

Tags: c#, wcf, config

EDIT: Already fixed it... I only had to change the Project properties and enable SSL.

---

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I'm developing a WCF service that will be hosted in an IIS server with SSL certificate.

My code works perfectly fine when I upload it to the server (that have all the certificates), but since I added the security to the web config, it crash when I try to debug it on my local machine.

I'm using the following web config for a SOAP service that don't need the SSL certificate and a REST service that need it:

```
<configuration>
...
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SOAPEndPoint" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureBinding" >
          <security mode="Transport"></security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="xxx.WS">
        <endpoint address="SOAP" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="SOAPEndPoint" contract="xxx.ISerSoap" />
        <endpoint address="api" binding="webHttpBinding" name="RESTEndPoint" contract="xxx.ISerRest" behaviorConfiguration="RestBehavior" bindingConfiguration="SecureBinding"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RestBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I want to be able to debug it without the need to change the web config each time I open it during debug and if I have to upload it to the server.

Someone knows a way to bypass the security when I call it in debug mode? Or an easy way to add support of https on my localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Just find that the solution was to activate "SSL Enabled = true" on the project properties windows.